# PUT and DELETE methods in nginx

Tags: nginx, http

Is there anyway how to enable such http methods like PUT and DELETE for specific virtual host in [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) ?

I need it for my RESTfull server application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using nginx to proxy to your application. nginx doesn't require any additional configuration to support methods like PUT and DELETE (at least not when using HTTP proxying, not sure about FastCGI).

Comment: yep you are right thank you. I have tested wrong this is why this question is opened up.

Answer (score 2):

You must set `proxy_http_version 1.1;` for PUT to work.